# Is there any english, preferably simple proof of Deza's theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, extremal-combinatorics

One of the theorem I find most fasicnating is Deza's theorems: We are given $S$, a $d$ uniform family of subsets of $[n]$, such that there exists a number $a$ so that for any two elements of $S$, $s_1$ and $s_2$, their intersection is of size $a$. Deza's theorem then says that if $|S|>d^2-d+1$, then $S$ is a sunflower: the intersection of all its elements is the same as the intersection of any $2$ of its elements. This is tight in some cases (for example when we have a project plane, its lines give a tight example).

However, for some darn reason, his original paper was in French, and I can find no good source online. Help please.

Comment: Why not read the French paper? Mathematical French doesn't use that much vocabulary, and there are good translation resources available. Failing that, can you post a link to the French paper? Is it online?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I don't speak French, and I think that wonderful theorems such as this one from 1973 should be available in English on the internet. In fact, I plan to do this( write it up on Wikipedia) after understand the proof. Papers seem to be refrencing this one: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X73900654 .

Comment: I don't speak French either, but I translate math from it, when I need to. I recommend trying it; it's a worthwhile challenge, and I promise it's easier than you think. I'd translate this one for you, and TeX it up, for $15/page.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I'll pass. But if you're willing to give a outline that will hopefully take you less effort I can give 15 thanks.

Comment: Well, can you tell from looking at it if there's a particular passage you want to know the details of?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I'm afraid I don't have a good grasp on it, and I remain hopeful we will not need to translate French but rather find a English savior who knows the proof.

Comment: I'm looking over it... section 3: "Démonstration du théorème principal" is "Proof of the main theorem". It boils down to 6 lemmas.

Comment: Do you know what is meant by an $(m,2k,n)$-code?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I think they mean a code of length $m$ with distance $2k$, the $n$ probably means how many code words we have.

Comment: If you'd like, I can translate the statements of the 6 lemmas without too much trouble. Should I put that content in an answer?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Yeah I guess it'd help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some statements of results from the paper. Each result here has its own proof, some long, some short. If you can say one proof in particular that you need translated, I'll see what I can do. Keep in mind, I don't *actually* know French, so I make no guarantees as to speed.

> Lemma 3.1: For every $(m,2k,n)$-code, and every integer $1\leq s\leq n$, we have: $t_s(m-t_s)\leq mk$.

(very short proof)

> Lemma 3.2: For every $(m,2k,n)$-code $X$ such that:
>
> $$t_s\leq \frac{m+2k-1}{k+1}-1$$
>
> (for all $1\leq s\leq n$), we have $t_s\leq 1$ for all $1\leq s\leq n$.

(long proof)

> Lemma 3.3: Every $(m,2k,n)$-code, such that $m\not\in[4,k^2+k+2]$ satisfies the condition $t_s\leq 1$ for $s\in [1,n]$.

(fairly short proof, using 2 previous lemmas)

> Lemma 3.4: An $(m,2k,n)$-code is trivial if and only if $t_s\leq 1$ for $1\leq s\leq n$.

(shortish proof)

> Lemma 3.5: If $m\geq 4$ and there exists a non-trivial $(m,2k)$-code, then, for every $m'\in[4,m]$, there exists a non-trivial $(m',2k)$-code.

(shortish proof)

> Lemma 3.6: If there exists a non-trivial $(m,2k)$-code, we have $N(m,k)<mk$. Otherwise, we have $N(m,k)=mk$.

(shortish proof)

After this, there's a paragraph saying it would be interesting to find certain spectra of numbers for which non-trivial codes exist, and then the real proof occurs in a paragraph on p. 350 beginning "Passons maintenant..."

Statement of the main theorem:

> Theorem 1.1: Let $m$ and $k$ be two integers such that $m>k \geq 1$; then we have:
>
> i) There exists a number $N(m,k)$ such that a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of an $(m,2k,n)$-code is that $n\geq N(m,k)$
>
> ii) $N(m,k)\leq mk$ and there exists a number $f(k)$ such that $f(k)\geq 4$ and $N(m,k)=mk$ if and only if $m\in [4,f(k)]$
>
> iii) There exists a trivial $(m,2k)$-code and its length is greater than or equal to $mk$. There exists an $(m,2k)$-code, different from a trivial code, if and only if $m\in[4,f(k)]$.
>
> iv) $f(k)\leq k^2+k+2$ and $f(k)=k^2+k+2$ if there exists a $PG(2,k)$.

Comment: Thanks, I have to go now but I will look tomorrow and ask accordingly